# Does unlisted app distribution support App Clips?

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to distribute an iOS app with an App Clip. The iOS app does not need to be discoverable in the App Store and thus I am considering distributing it as an [unlisted app](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/). However, the app contains an App Clip that needs to be publicly available: anybody should be able to open the App Clip (via a QR code).

Is this supported? Or the App Clip associated domain won't be detected because the app is unlisted?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

App Clips are always associated with a publicly available app. When your app is not publicly available, but instead requires a special link, it is not eligible for App Clips.

Comment: Actually that's wrong because I've just tried and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually just tried. I published the app as an unlisted app and the App Clip works well.